# Using a QSplitter with layouts

Tags: qt

In my app I have a treeview at the top with some buttons above it related to the treeview. Below this I have a table view, again with some buttons related to it.  I have a QVBoxLayout top and bottom.

Please see the screen show.

What I'd like to do is be able to adjust the size of the top and bottom in the way that a QPlitter allows you to do.  But ... a QSplitter only accepts widgets, not layouts.

I'd like to be able to drag where the red line is in the screen shot.

I'm creating the layout in C++ not in the designer.

Is there a way to do this?

[image: Layout showing where I'd like a splitter]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Wrap your widgets inside another widget, like so:

```
Splitter
 ├──Top Widget
 │   └──Layout 1
 │       ├──Button 1
 │       ├──Button 2
 │       └──Text Area 1
 └──Bottom Widget
     └──Layout 2
         ├──Button 3
         ├──Button 4
         └──Text Area 2
```

Example:

```
QWidget *topWidget = new QWidget;
topWidget->setLayout(layout1);
...
splitter->addWidget(topWidget);
splitter->addWidget(bottomWidget);
```

Comment: The Best scheme ever seen!

Comment: Thank you, svlasov.  What might the Top Widget and Bottom widget be?  Just a QWidget?  How would I add a layout to that widget?

Comment: Just a plain `QWidget`.